# Generically render an arbritrary NSArray or NSDictionary in a NSOutlineView

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsdictionary, nsoutlineview

When using XCode and you open a "plist" file you get the contents in a nice outline view.

In my project [CoreDataUtility](https://github.com/yepher/CoreDataUtility) I would like to do something very similar. In core data a developer can store NSDictionary and NSArray as a transformable object. I would like to be able to present those object in a nice tree view instead of just dumping the description to a NSTextView.

I'm sure I can start coding it and get it to work but first I wanted to check if anyone knows how to get NSTreeView to do this intrinsically or if anyone has sample code that already does something similar?

Thanks for any help you might be able to offer.

Comment: NSTreeView with NSTreeController works with NSDictionary almost “out of the box”. Check samples provided by Apple first.

Comment: For an NSDictionary, I'd think you could set the NSTreeController class to NSObject and the childrenKeyPath to allValues.  With NSTreeController, you just have to make sure to use the representedObject on the NSTreeNode to get your real object rather than the proxy.

Comment: @thom_ek, So if the dictionary has values that are Arrays or Dictionaries you think it will work almost out of the box? That is good news. I've looked through the apple demo code but did not find anything that was this nice. I will look again as that will be a huge help.

Comment: @Yepher Now I can't find exact sample :(

Comment: My mistake - not NSTreeView, but NSOutlineView of course :)

Comment: I guess one easy way would be to save the NSDictionary or NSArray to a temp file and open it with the system plist viewer. Is that only available if XCode is installed?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use nested `NSDictionary` objects directory with an `NSTreeController` because a dict's children wouldn't be of the correct form, as you'd always need same-named keyPaths for the value you want to show in the `NSOutlineView`'s columns.

However, you can easily convert the nested `NSDictionary` objects into a slightly different representation that meets this requirement.

Consider you have an outlineview with two columns. You'd bind the first column's Value to the Tree Controller's `arrangedObjects.col1` and the second to `arrangedObjects.col2`.

Then here's the code for creating a suitable `NSDictionary`:

```
- (NSDictionary*) makeNodeFrom:(NSObject*)value withName:(NSString*)name {
    NSMutableDictionary *result = NSMutableDictionary.dictionary;   // has keys: name, value, children, isLeaf, count
    result[@"col1"] = name;
    if ([value isKindOfClass:NSDictionary.class]) {
        NSMutableArray *children = NSMutableArray.array;
        [(NSDictionary*)value enumerateKeysAndObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSObject *obj, BOOL *stop) {
            [children addObject:[self makeNodeFrom:obj withName:key]];
        }];
        result[@"children"] = children;
        result[@"count"] = @(children.count);
    } else {
        result[@"isLeaf"] = @YES;
        result[@"col2"] = value;
    }
    return result;
}

// return the model from a generic dictionary:
- (NSDictionary)myModel {
    NSDictionary *sampleDict = @{
        @"key1": @"value1,
        @"node": @{
            @"key2": @"value2"
        }
    };
    return [self makeNodeFrom:sampleDict withName:@"root"];
}
```

In the Tree Controller, bind its Content Array to `myModel`, and set its keyPath properties as follows:

- Children: `children`
- Count: `count`
- Left: `isLeaf`